# how to fix NoSuchElementException in my code

Tags: java

How can i remove `NoSuchElementException` in my code?
i am applying `hasNextLine` also but it is not taking it then also.

```
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception{

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int t=sc.nextInt();
        Scanner sc1=new Scanner(System.in);
        String c[]=new String[t];
        String d[]=new String[t];
        int b[]=new int[t];
        for(int i=0;i<t;i++){
          b[i]=sc.nextInt();
          String a[]=sc1.nextLine().split(" ");
          c[i]=a[0];
          d[i]=a[1];
        }

        for(int j=0;j<t;j++){
          new X().substr(c[j],d[j]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: At which line does the exception occur?

Comment: Why do you create 2 input scanners? I'd say that is really weird.

Comment: What is `X`? You're creating it at the end. `new X().substr(c[j],d[j]);`

Comment: at  String a[]=sc1.nextLine().split(" ");@ NeplatnyUdaj

Answer (score 2):

Do a `sc.hasNextLine()` check before scanning the next line to make sure the next line exists. You don't need scanner declaration twice.